# simple html5 button trigger postback in asp.net webform

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a simple HTML button to trigger jquery function but when i add this button to webform it triggers post-back.

Play

I tried adding `OnClientClick="myfunction(); return false;"` but it sill postback.

How can i use simple button without postback

Comment: I resolved this issue by using div instead. It would still be nice to know why it is happening.

Comment: Can u show your button code ?

Comment: You say "a simple HTML button". Is it an ASP.NET Button control? If you use `<asp:Button OnClientClick="return false;" ... />`, then it should not post back to the server. If you used an HTML input controls (`<input type="submit" ... />`), the `OnClientClick` probably has no meaning for it; you may try with the `onclick` event instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding stoppropagation() to your function

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `input` tag with `type="submit"` or `button` tag with `type="submit"` than clicking it will cause the page to `submit`. So you may need to use `type="button"`.

```
<input type="button" onclick="yourfunction()" value="SomeValue" />
```